# HttpPost controller method not being called

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post

I'm trying to make an HTTP Post request to a controller method I did, but it is never getting called. It always returns a status code of 200 but it's not called and doesn't return anything

This is where I do the call

```
private async Task louerFilm()
{
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new();
    locationRequest.IdClient = "99999";
    locationRequest.IdFilm = "99999";

    var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider;
    var token = await customAuthStateProvider.GetToken();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

    var locationResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/films/louerFilm", locationRequest);
}
```

This is my controller method

```
[HttpPost("louerFilm")]
[Authorize]
public int LouerFilm([FromBody] LocationRequest locationRequest)
{
    Console.WriteLine("here");
    var session = _nHibernateHelper.OpenSession();

    try
    {
        var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec pLouerCopieFilm :p1, :p2")
            .SetParameter("p1", locationRequest.IdClient)
            .SetParameter("p2", locationRequest.IdFilm)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine("here");` is never called, but the response body prints as this:

```
locationResponse = StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent, Headers:
 {
   Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 02:51:13 GMT
   Server: Kestrel
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 }
```

Edit: turns out it's being called but not correctly, I wasn't managing the returned status codes correctly. Either way, it never outputs the `Console.WrtieLine("here")` that I added at the start of the method in Controller.

Comment: what is the `Console.WriteLine(locationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Comment: @QiangFu `System.Threading.Tasks.Task\`1[System.String]`

Comment: if I do `Console.WriteLine(await locationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` I get `-1`

Comment: sorry how about one `Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)`

Comment: @QiangFu still `-1`

Comment: Does -1 come from the catch{}? what if you return -2?

Comment: @QiangFu it prints `-2` now, does that mean it's actually calling the method? how come the `Console.WriteLine` in it doesn't show anything?

Comment: how about delete the `var session..`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255775/discussion-between-luis-angel-urena-lopez-and-qiang-fu).